# How to hide change sets in RTC source control

Tags: rtc

Is it possible to hide a change set in RTC source control ?

I don't seee an option to perform this. I have some source code that is in a component that needs to be hidden, but I cannot restrict the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article "[Controlling access to source control in Rational Team Control](https://jazz.net/library/article/215)" doesn't mention anything regarding read access within a component of a change set.

In other words, a change set, especially one delivered, cannot be hidden.

Independently of any change set, you can ["Read protect some files or folders within a component but give public access to others"](https://jazz.net/library/article/215#protect_some_files):

[image: file permissions]

Comment: only method I can see of hiding change sets then is to just create a new source repo of an existing stream, disconnect this repo and share the projects to a new stream. This will just contain the inital 'Share' change set. Disadvantage of this method is that will lost visibility of all change sets.

Comment: @user470184 I agree. It is a workaround, but not an ideal solution.